# XMLHttpRequest cannot load - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' with Meteor & FSCollection

Tags: javascript, meteor, http-status-code-503

I have some trouble with upload csv file when the app is deployed on Meteor Server. It works on localhost.

I have this error :

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://smsgalaxy.meteor.com' is therefore not
>   allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.

I tried to see the FSCollection documentation. I have read something like don't worry about CORS.

I tried also to add this code in the server side from http://enable-cors.org/server_meteor.html :

```
// Listen to incoming HTTP requests, can only be used on the server
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  return next();
});
```

Doesn't work, alas.

Need help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the response headers? Is the code actually called on the server?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess Collection FS doesn't work with Meteor deploy... I have read a commentary on Reddit :

> All local storage options hinge on
>   https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS which doesn't work
>   with meteor deploy (as far as I know). The way it works is it breaks
>   the file into chunks and stores the binary data in a Mongo FS
>   Collection.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Meteor/comments/2ove4s/how_should_i_handle_file_upload/